# post the nested json object to the wcf rest service method-objects fields are null

Tags: json, rest

When i post the nested json object to the wcf rest service method,objects fields  are showing null.
This is my data contract

```
[DataContract]
public class EmpContract
{
    [DataMember]
    public string EmpID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class people
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<EmpContract> EmpCont{ get; set; }       
}
```

and this is my rest method

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetEmp", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse)]
    string GetEmp(people objPeople);
```

and this is my **JSON** code

```
type: "POST",
                url: "",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "objPeople": { "EmpCont": [{ "EmpID": "1", "EmpName": "1" }] } }),                    
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                processData: true,
```

kindly help me to fix this problem.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sayyed to format and i finally found the solution for this problem.Its a json data format issue. i changed the format like

data: JSON.stringify({ "EmpCont": [{ "EmpID": "1", "EmpName": "aaaaa" }]}),

and its working fine now.